# Longest common Subsequence generalization for N lists (for merging)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

## The goal

I have several data from different CSV files, that I want to merge in a single one, preserving as much as possible the order of the columns.

Say the first file has columns `[A, B, D]` and file 2 has `[A, C, D]`, I want the resulting file to contain columns `[A, B, C, D]`

## First approach

I've come across the [Longest common subsequence algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence), which allows me to merge two files, while preserving the columns order, so the first goal is a problem solved.

There are some edge cases the algorithm can't detect, like `[A, B, D]` + `[A, C, D]` which picks at random either `[A, B, C, D]` or `[A, C, B, D]`, and I can live with it.

## The problem - Generalization

The wikipedia article states:

> A longest common subsequence (LCS) is the longest subsequence common to all sequences in a set of sequences **(often just two sequences)**

and there is no explanation about it.

In practice, I have several files to merge together, and I simply tried an iterative approach:

```
1: [ A, C, D ]
2: [ A, B, D ]
3: [ B, C ]
```

I tried merging that way : `((1 + 2) + 3)`, which gives me `[ A, C, B, D ]` + `[ B, C ]` which gives `[ A, C, B, D ]` (since I don't duplicate columns, I'm just ignoring columns that are already there).

But in that specific case, there *was* a way to use the know the "correct" order, using 3 as a way to disambiguate.

Interestingly, changing the merge order would have solved the issue for that specific case.

I want a solution that :

- Doesn't depend on the order of the files I merge
- Can get clues from all the files to resolve "conflicts" (as in "a git merge conflict")
- Ideally, is written in typescript
- Runs in less than 10 seconds for 20 files of 50 columns each
- Most of the time, columns are the same from file to file, but sometimes, you may face a file that is up to 50% different from other files. swapped columns between files are unlikely and should not happen under normal conditions.

## Investigations

### LCS with N dimensions

I thought about using a matrix with N dimensions, but with a 50^20 matrix, that doesn't seem reasonable

### "k-way merge"

That algorithm seem to work well for "sorted lists", in the sense that given two items A and B, there is a relationship that can return whether `A <= B`, but that's not the case here.

### Graph algorithm

Given two consecutive items A and B in the list, draw an edge saying "A is before B" in the list, do it for all items in all the lists.

Now that you have filled your notepad with circles and arrows everywhere, "just walk the graph to resolve issues". Oh, and if there is a cycle in the graph, find a way to solve that. I have no idea how to do that...

I have no idea where to start, and any help would be appreciated

Comment: "so the first goal is a problem solved"  What is the second goal?

Comment: The second goal is "resolving the edge case" that occurs with generalization (section "The problem"). Sorting is unreliable since it depends on the order of the files, and it cannot resolve the "conflicts" by itself.

Comment: "There are some edge cases  ... I can live with it."  So you are now saying you cannot live with it?

Comment: Either 1) you are overthinking this, or 2) I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, or 3) the spreadsheet example isn't the problem that you're actually trying to solve. The columns in a spreadsheet are labeled alphabetically, so there is a "correct" order for the columns. For example, if the input is `[ADF] + [ABF] + [CE]` then the output is `[ABCDEF]` simply because those are the columns that the files use.

Comment: @ravenspoint : all I'm saying is that when there is no way to know as a human, I can accept that the algorithm swaps the columns B and C. But if there is a file that tells that B must be before C, then the algorithm should "know"

Comment: @user3386109: you're right, I'm just using letters for the sake of explanation, but columns are actually labelled, like "date","last_name", "first_name","grade" (not a real example), but I want to keep that order, grade shouldn't come between first _name and last_name

Comment: I see. Then what you have in each file is a list of dependencies. You just make one big list of dependencies, and then perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). As you already mentioned, cycles are not allowed.

Comment: But there shouldn't be any cycles because "swapped columns between files are unlikely and should not happen". If the graph does have a cycle, and you use [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm), you'll end up at the `return error` line.  Instead of returning an error, just delete one of the remaining edges, and try again.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to implement that. They are unlikely, but users beign users, that can occur and the case should be handled properly.